# Trouble with CUDA 5.0 on a laptop

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, laptop, cuda

I am currently trying to run a program called MC-GPU V1.3 ( https://code.google.com/p/mcgpu/ ), on my laptop.

First off, let me explain my situation.

Using a Lenovo y400 Laptop with Nvidia 650m
Running Ubuntu 12.10
Installed Cuda-5.0, all samples compiled and I ran quite a few to test that they worked
Using Proprietary driver, not dev-driver that came with Cuda-5.0
Wrote a quick "Hello world" cuda program that compiled and ran
I am compiled with the given lines in the code to create the MC-GPU_v1.3.x and run the simple geometry using ../MC-GPU_v1.3.x MC-GPU_v1.3_6voxels.in | tee MC-GPU_v1.3_6voxels.out

I can compile and run the simple geometery code using the CPU compilation but the GPU part I cannot get to work.

I switch to console, disable the Xserver by calling service lightdm stop and init 3
When I try to run the code after doing this, I get all print outs to the point of where it states: starting the Monte Carlo Loop Phase and then it tells me that I am executing 7813 blocks of 128 threads with 100 histories in each thread for a total of 100006400 histories in total. After this output, I get an error from line 891 in MC-GPU_v1.3.cu that !!Kernel execution failed while simulating particle tracks!!  : (4) unspecified launch failure.

I am assuming that I am getting the error from where the code first tries to access the memory of the GPU, but unsure why I am getting these errors. Since I am running a sample I am hoping that this is a simple problem of not compiling something correctly or missing a step in attempting the simulation. Please let me know if anyone has time to help or if I should share any other information.

Can someone with a similar set up help me understand why this isn't working on my laptop and how I can get it to run? I am willing to help someone to compile and run the program on their system if need be to speed things along if someone is willing to help me troubleshoot things.

Thank you,
Dave

Comment: I would like to know if there is any Office variant including the Monte Carlo simulations module by default or that could be added afterwards at no cost. Do you have any ideas of anyone?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking here. MC-GPU is a free program and can be found in my link in the above post. It is written to run Linux, so if by Office you mean a Windows program, this is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the installs of everything were fine there were just too many calls in the Monte Carlo simulation and my laptop could not handle the inputs. Since I was running someone else's code I just adjusted the kernel inputs and run the job multiple times and compile the results.